# How to prevent scientific display of a float?

Tags: java, decimal

I have the following output

output =4.08E-4

output =8.9E-5

output =0.978461

output =0.224577

Now the thing I don't get is for **4.08E-4** - I assume it is a negative exponential and given <0 it returns true but is there another way of displaying this in decimal format?

Comment: I have updated the title with the relevant (keyword) information. Of course, a good bit is missing, like *"what generates the output in the post"*, but whatever is, is using scientific notation to do so for certain values.

Comment: The relevant information would be - how is he doing the actual output? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are trying to print a float/double using System.out.println(...).

This eventually calls the `public static String toString()` method of Float (or Double). Either way, if you read the Javadoc it states:

> If m is less than 10-3 or greater than or equal to 107, then it is
>   represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let n be
>   the unique integer such that 10n <= m < 10n+1; then let a be the
>   mathematically exact quotient of m and 10n so that 1 <= a < 10. The
>   magnitude is then represented as the integer part of a, as a single
>   decimal digit, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by decimal digits
>   representing the fractional part of a, followed by the letter 'E'
>   ('\u0045'), followed by a representation of n as a decimal integer, as
>   produced by the method Integer.toString(int).

You can get around this using `System.out.printf()`, like this:

```
double d = 0.000408;

System.out.println(d);
System.out.printf("%f", d);
```

This prints:

```
4.08E-4
0,000408
```

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(4.08e-4);

0.000408
```

Answer (score 1):

I use NumberFormat class-

```
        double d = 0.000408;            
        //For considering 4 digits after decimal place
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);            
        nf.setGroupingUsed(false);

        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(nf.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is either the class NumberFormat or the printf function, either one would work.